# Programatically view a CRM report without access to Reporting Server

Tags: c#, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

Is there any way that I can view a report (Sales > Reports) using C# without having access to the reporting server?

I am attempting to write a tool that monitors the health of our CRM servers (entity records in right place etc) and as such I want the tool to be located somewhere where it has access to each CRM instance (ranging from 2013 on prem to 2016 Online).

The reason for this is that we havea  report that does all the heavy lifting of checking the health of all entities,settings,records etc and i just want to be able to programatically examine this report (via xml parsing) and tell the user the result.

I tried using the html scraping, direct URL approach: `/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?Id=xxxxxxx` however, perhaps predictably, the returned HTML was just a page prompting for a login.

I do have all of the credentials to make an Xrm Service connection but I am not sure of how to access reports using this.

Is going through the reporting services asmx the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can call SSRS WebService in your C#.

To do so you shall add a Web Service reference:
[Instruction](https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/guides/infinitydevguide/Subsystems/infps-developer-help/Content/AddingWebReference.htm)

Consider that there are 3 webservices in SSRS

> There are three endpoints available for managing objects on a report
> server, **ReportService2005**, **ReportService2006**, and **ReportService2010**.
>
> The **ReportService2005** endpoint is used for managing objects on a
> report server that is configured for native mode.
>
> The **ReportService2006** endpoint is used for managing objects on a report
> server that is configured for SharePoint integrated mode.
>
> The **ReportService2010** endpoint merges the functionalities of
> ReportService2005 and ReportService2006 and can manage objects on a
> report server that that are configured for either native or SharePoint
> integrated mode.

[Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/methods/report-server-web-service-endpoints?view=sql-server-2017)